# Late 20th century story, probably in Analog, about "glory rings"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember a late 20th century story, possibly in *Analog*, maybe in *Asimov's*, about an expedition in search of "glory rings".

In the story, "glory rings" were rings of smallish objects orbiting stars or planets in young star systems. Some process would cause the small objects in the rings to be made out of heavy elements and metals, or else be coated with them.

And the "glory rings" would last for a short time, cosmically speaking, before they would be destroyed in a way which would destroy their concentration of heavy elements. Thus they were fabulously valuable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

["Rings of Glory"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49460), a novella by [Thomas R. Dulski](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?12208) in [*Analog Science Fiction/Science Fact*, July 1982](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57132).

> "Well, glory rings are very special rings, miss. Very special." Brightbar's large blue eyes held a twinkle. "The planets with glory rings around them have only ever been found in very young solar systems—nobody seems to know exactly why. Glory rings *are* gold, like the man said, *and* platinum, *and* iridium, *and* uranium . . . and, you name it. It's there, somewhere among those rings. . . ."

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I wanted the story id for my answer to this question. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/239829/under-what-conditions-could-a-gold-planet-form/239837#239837